# defining map with integer and string

Tags: c++, dictionary, include

Im learning about map, this is the first code Im trying, I want to have a map of intgeres and strings.
here is my code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <map>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

// int map <key, val> :D    sorted by key
map <int,string> mymap;

int main(){
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    int a;  string b;
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        cin >> a >> b;
        pair<int, string> p;
        //mymap.insert(pair<int, string>(a,b));
        mymap[a] = b;
    }

    map<int, int>::iterator it = mymap.begin();

    for(it = mymap.begin(); it!=mymap.end() ; it++)
        cout << it->first << ' ' << it->second << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

but I get so much errors I dont Understand where Im wrong.
Would you please help me to understand where Im wrong?!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't tag things C if they aren't. Also, all but the first error reported may be inaccurate. Next, while the code is nearly an MCVE, where are the error-messages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

line 23 typo:

```
    map<int, string>::iterator it = mymap.begin();
```